# Interleaving of two strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion

I have two strings `str1` and `str2`. 
Is there any algorithm that can be used in order to print out all interleavings of the two strings using recursion?

Update:

```
public class Interleave {


    private String resultString[] = new String[10];
    private String[] interStr(String str1, String str2){
    int n = ((Factorial.factorial(str1.length() + str2.length())) / (Factorial.factorial(str1.length()) * Factorial.factorial(str2.length())));
    //n is number of interleavings based on (str1.length()+str2.length())! / (str1.length()! * str2.length()!)
    if(str1.length() == 0){
        resultString[0] = str2;
        return resultString;
    }

    if(str2.length() == 0){
        resultString[0] = str1;
        return resultString;
    }

    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            resultString[i]= str1.substring(0, 1) + interStr(str1.substring(1), str2.substring(1));

        }
    }
    return resultString;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interleave obj = new Interleave();
    obj.interStr("12", "abc");
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.resultString.length; i ++){
        System.out.println(obj.resultString[i]);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I've tried different things but instead of trying to re-invent the wheel why not to use something much more meaningful?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: May I ask why was my post edited?

Comment: because people expect to see that you have attempted to solve a problem yourself first, rather than you expecting someone to do it for you. Not to mention it looks alot like homework.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I do NOT want anybody to solve it for me.

Comment: If you are presented with a problem would you solved it using your "algorithm" or would you rather use something that has already been available and proved to be much more efficient that yours?

Comment: How do you define "interleaving" of two strings?

Comment: @Nath: if it is was homework, myself. Otherwise, I'd do both. Mixing up 2 strings is hardly a world shattering algorithm.

Comment: @Paulo Ebermann: The first print out could be just adding the two strings. Then exchanging _n_ and _n-1_ characters of this string, then exchanging the _n-1_ with _n-2_ and so on.

Comment: @Mitch: How about if you approach the eight queens problem, for exmple? You'd be still using your algorithm?

Comment: @Nath: you are straying into the irrelevant and personal. How about you update your question with just one of your attempts?

Comment: @Mitch: The code above is not doing the task. I was just playing with some recursion ideas... And by the way I don't take it personally nor I think my example with the eight queens was irrelevant.

Comment: @Mitch: You don't have to always assume that if anyone, who doesn't express clearly what (s)he has done, is cheating or trying to steal other people's work. And no - it's N-O-T homework.

Comment: @Nath *"..why was my post edited? "* See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/ BTW - the code block in your current post is not correctly formatted.  I'll leave that for you to fix.

Comment: @Nath: i have no idea what you are going on about. Lets leave it at that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question simply asked whether a recursive algorithm exists for the problem, and the answer is yes.  To find it, look for the base case and then for the "step".

The base case is when one of the two strings are empty:

- `interleave(s1, "")` = {s1}
- `interleave("", s2)` = {s2}

Notice the order of the arguments doesn't really matter, because

- `interleave("ab", "12")` = {"ab12", "a1b2", "1ab2", "a12b", "1a2b", "12ab"} = `interleave("12", "ab")`

So since the order doesn't matter we'll look at recursing on the length of the first string.

Okay so let's see how one case leads to the next.  I'll just use a concrete example, and you can generalize this to real code.

- `interleave("", "abc")` = {"abc"}
- `interleave("1", "abc")` = {"1abc", "a1bc", "ab1c", "abc1"}
- `interleave("12", "abc")` = {"12abc", "1a2bc", "1ab2c", "1abc2", "a12bc", "a1b2c", "a1bc2", "ab12c", "ab1c2" "abc12"}

So everytime we added a character to the first string, we formed the new result set by adding the new character to all possible positions in the old result set.  Let's look at exactly how we formed the third result above from the second.  How did each element in the second result turn into elements in the third result when we added the "2"?

- "1abc" => "12abc", "1a2bc", "1ab2c", "1abc2"
- "a1bc" => "a12bc", "a1b2c", "a1bc2"
- "ab1c" => "ab12c", "ab1c2"
- "abc1" => "abc12"

Now look at things this way:

- "1abc" => {1 w | w = interleave("2", "abc")}
- "a1bc" => {a1 w | w = interleave("2", "bc")}
- "ab1c" => {ab1 w | w = interleave("2", "c")}
- "abc1" => {abc1 w | w = interleave("2", "")}

Although one or two examples doesn't prove a rule in general, in this case you should be able to infer what the rule is.  You will have a loop, with recursive calls inside it.

This is actually a little more fun to do with pure functional programming, but you tagged the question with Java.

Hopefully this is a start for you.  If you get stuck further you can do a web search for "interleaving strings" or "interleaving lists".  There are some solutions out there.

*EDIT*:

Okay I just wrote the silly thing!  It's a lot of fun to write these things in scripting languages, so I thought it would be great to see what it looked like in Java.  Not as bad as I thought it would be!  Here it is, packaged as an entire Java application.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Interleaver {

    /**
     * Returns a list containing all possible interleavings of two strings.
     * The order of the characters within the strings is preserved.
     */
    public static List<String> interleave(String s, String t) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (t.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(s);
        } else if (s.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(t);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
                char c = t.charAt(0);
                String left = s.substring(0, i);
                String right = s.substring(i);
                for (String u : interleave(right, t.substring(1))) {
                    result.add(left + c + u);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Prints some example interleavings to stdout.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(interleave("", ""));
        System.out.println(interleave("a", ""));
        System.out.println(interleave("", "1"));
        System.out.println(interleave("a", "1"));
        System.out.println(interleave("ab", "1"));
        System.out.println(interleave("ab", "12"));
        System.out.println(interleave("abc", "12"));
        System.out.println(interleave("ab", "1234"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I do understand your algorithm but I am having hard time putting it in real code.

Comment: Hint:  The notation `{x w | w = f(y)}` means the set of all strings made by concatenating `x` to each of the strings returned by calling `f(y)`.  It will turn into a `for` loop.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You mean that `"1abc" = "1 + interleave("2", "abc")` , `"a1bc" = "a1" + interleave("2", "bc")` and so on?

Comment: @Nath It's kind of hard to pick out exactly what's wrong, but I do see you are using arrays (and fixed one at size 10, which is not a general solution) instead of lists because as you say you haven't learned them yet.  This is not a great problem to use arrays for, so I suggest you bite the bullet and learn lists.  To that end, I went ahead and just wrote a complete Java application for you.  It should run as is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Ray. I wouldn't be able to do it myself. One question - in the inner `for` loop

Comment: Stupid editing restrictions. I cannot edit my comment for more than 5 min.

Comment: So, I am reposting again the last comment: Thank you very much for your help, Ray. I wouldn't be able to do it myself. One question - in the inner `for` loop how the variable, that is returned by the recursive call, which here is a `List` is given to the variable u, which is a `String`?

Comment: Actually ignore my last question. I guess the answer is because the `List` contains elements that are strings. Upon every return `u` accepts the returned element(string).

Comment: In Java when you say `for (T x : c)` it means run a for loop using the variable `x` of type `T` to go through all the elements of the collection `c`.  The result of the recursive call is a list.  The first time through the loop `u` is the first value of the list; the second time through `u` is the second and so on.  The important thing is that the call is made once, THEN the for-loop runs through it, using the variable `u` to take on each element of the list one at a time.

Comment: So far in my programs I've been using the `enhanced for loop` when the collection has already been filled up with elements in advance. **After** the collection has been filled with the elements I have the statement, for example `for(int value: array){...}` in order to go through the array (in your code it would be through the list). This is actually the part where I got confused. Instead of filling up the list first and then having `String u: list` you write `String u: function()`

Comment: I apologize for keep asking questions since you've already written the code for me but there is still something that I don't understand. You are saying that the important thing is that the call is made once. As far as I understand every time when the compiler reaches `for (String u : interleave(right, t.substring(1))) {` we go deeper and deeper until we reach the base case, while you are saying that the call is made once. Would you mind giving me some more clarification on this? I just want to **understand** everything that you've written. Not to just copy it and use it.

Comment: Well yes the call is made multiple times with in the for-i loop, and multiple times as we descend deeper into levels of recursion.  I just meant that it was NOT called multiple times in the for-u loop.  If you look only at the for loop that says `for (String u : interleave(...)` you call interleave only once and then you iterate.  Contrast that with the classic-for statement like `for (i=0; f(x); i++)` where `f(x)` is called every time within that loop.  Hope that answers your question!

Comment: I thought `for (String u : interleave(...)` calls interleave(...) multiple times. Personally in my little Java experience I've never seen for-statements like `for (i=0; f(x); i++)`. Can you, please point me to some examples where I can see simpler cases? I want to understand how exactly it works.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14:  In `for(e1;e2;e3)` the expression `e2` is evaluated every time through the loop.  In `for (type x: a)` where `a` is an array expression, the expression `a` is evaluated only once.

Comment: OK, when I debug your code I see that `for (String u : interleave(right, t.substring(1))) {` calls `interleave` a couple of times. It winds and unwinds. Or may be there is something that I don't understand.

Comment: Not within the for loop it doesn't!  Do `System.out.print("+")` at the beginning of `interleave` and put a `System.out.print(".")` inside the for-u loop.  You will see ranges of consecutive dots between plus signs.  That will prove what I said. :)

Comment: I've put `System.out.print("+")` at the beginning of `interleave` and `System.out.print(".")` at the beginning of `for (String u : interleave(right, t.substring(1))) {`. In `main()` I have `System.out.println(interleave("12", "abc"));`. Through debugger I still see a couple of `interleave()` calls. Please, note that I am not trying to oppose what you are saying at all. I just don't get what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: This solution looks very complex. See the code posted below by me. That is much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question correctly - that you want all the permutations of all the characters in both strings, then the following code will help. You will need to write your own swap function, and somehow obtain an array of all the characters in both strings.
This algorithm will permute from the i'th element up to the n'th element in the array. It is in C++, I would include a reference to where the algorithm is from but I can't remember.

```
void getPermutationsR(char characters[], int n, int i) 
{
    if (i == n)
    {
        //Output the current permutation
    } 
    else
    {
        for (int j=i; j<n; j++) 
        {
            swap (characters, i, j);
            getPermutationsR(characters, n, i+1);
            swap (characters, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not what OP has asked.

Answer (score 1):

What you have now is a good start. The problem is that it returns just one string, instead a list of those.

Change your function to return a list of string, and then think about how you could combine several lists to produce all the output you want.

Comment: Yes, but then you will have to calculate the right length before. For a list, you can simply add the elements one-by-one.

Comment: OK.I see. I don't know why I have to enter at least 15 characters when adding a comment.

Comment: They want to avoid trivial comments like "OK. I see" :-p

Comment: I would try to use your suggestion and Ray Toal's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using recursive approach, easy to understand too

```
public class Interleave {

public static List<String> interleave(String first, String second){
    if(first.length() == 0){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(second);
        return list;
    }
    else if(second.length() == 0){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(first);
        return list;
    }
    else{
        char c1 = first.charAt(0);
        List<String> listA =  multiply(c1,interleave(first.substring(1),second));
        char c2 = second.charAt(0);
        List<String> listB =  multiply(c2,interleave(first,second.substring(1)));
        listA.addAll(listB);
        return listA;
    }
}


public static List<String> multiply(char c,List<String> list){
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String str : list){
            String res = Character.toString(c) + str;
            result.add(res);
        }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(interleave("ab", "1234"));
    System.out.println(interleave("a", "b"));
    System.out.println(interleave("ab", "cd"));
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the much better and simple to understand solution for this problem:

```
public class Interleaver {

    /**
     * Returns a list containing all possible interleavings of two strings.
     * The order of the characters within the strings is preserved.
     */
    public static String s1 = "abc";
    public static String s2 = "12";

    public static void interleave(int i, int j, String s) {

        if (i == s1.length() && j == s2.length()) {
            System.out.println("" + s);
        }

        if (i != s1.length()) {
            interleave(i + 1, j, s + s1.charAt(i));
        }

        if (j != s2.length()) {
            interleave(i, j + 1, s + s2.charAt(j));
        }

    }//Method ends here

    /**
     * Prints some example interleavings to stdout.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        interleave(0, 0, "");
    }//Method ends here
}//Class ends here
```

Program is using just simple recursive calls to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recursive solution:

```
public class Interleaving2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "ab";
        String y = "CD";
        int m = x.length();
        int n = y.length();
        char[] result = new char[m + n + 1];

        interleave(x, y, result, m, n, 0);
    }

    public static void interleave(String x, String y, char[] result, int m, int n, int i) {
        if (m == 0 && n == 0) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(result));
        }

        if (m != 0) {
            result[i] = x.charAt(0);
            interleave(x.substring(1), y, result, m - 1, n, i + 1);
        }

        if (n != 0) {
            result[i] = y.charAt(0);
            interleave(x, y.substring(1), result, m, n - 1, i + 1);
        }
    } 
}
```